# Помогите пожалуйста составить запрос

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть 2 таблицы:

И скрины с данными
[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

[![введите сюда описание изображения][2]][2]

Нужно достать только те апартаменты в которых количество зарезервированных меньше чем установлено для каждого апартамента, здесь должны быть выведены строки с id 2 и 3, так как в редисон уже все слоты заняты

Мой запрос выглядит вот так

```
select * from apartment as a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT r.id, sum(r.guests) as guests FROM reservation AS r 
GROUP BY r.apartment_id ) as r ON a.id = r.id
WHERE a.slots > r.guests
```

Но он мне показывает только записи в которых есть резервации, и не показывает qubus hotel

Я понимаю, что проблема заключается в where последнем, но как мне тогда отфильтровать чтобы не показывало редисон в котором слоты заняты?

Comment: Постановка задачи не корректна. Количество зарезервированных кроватей можно посчитать только на конкретную дату. Без указания даты сумма ни о чем не говорит. А что до самого запроса, то условие `a.slots > r.guests` при left join полностью уничтожает эффект от left, потому как r.guests может быть null, и условие не сработает. стоит писать `a.slots > coalesce(r.guests, 0)`

Comment: А еще совершенно не понятно почему вы в `ON` сравниваете id, если надо брать apartment_id из резерваций

Comment: @Mike спасибо за ваш совет с `coalesce` всё заработало, и на счёт apartmen_id тоже спасибо, не заметил этот косяк, вы мне очень помогли. Можете добавить это в ответ  я его приму как правильный. А на счёт даты то всё по порядку  сначала хотел сделать с местами, а позже добавить дату

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В изначальном запросе условие в where сводит на нет эффект от left так как r.guests может быть NULL. Необходимо учитывать такую возможность и сравнивать `a.slots > coalesce(r.guests, 0)`. Кроме того в условии ON допущена ошибка и сравниваются id двух таблиц, вместо использования apartment_id из reservation.

Кроме того следует говорить о занятости мест на конкретную дату и указывать это в запросе.

А вообще я бы написал этот запрос примерно так (но в некоторых случаях ваша трактовка может оказаться быстрее, надо сравнивать):

```
select a.*, sum(r.guests)
  from apartment as a
  left join reservation r ON r.apartment_id = a.id
    /* Добавить что то такое: AND ДАТА between r.start_date and r.end_date */
 GROUP BY a.apartment_id
HAVING a.slots > coalesce(sum(r.guests), 0)
```

Comment: а теперь если я хочу добавить дату то мне снова надо писать `COALESCE(r.start_date, 0)` ?

Comment: @Воланчик как я указал, в моем варианте дата должна быть в left join, а не в where, что бы в принципе цеплялись только нужные строки. В вашем варианте дата должна быть во внутреннем подзапросе, получающем количество, ни там ни там coalesce не нужны

Comment: понял, спасибо.